# Problem to access java.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hy!!

My Problem is that my terminal doesn't know the command java.
So i will solve the problem to access the java.exe directly.

Code:

```
'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe' -blabla
```

Exception:

```
Wrong Syntax
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your terminal to recognize command java you must put the entry `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\` in your Environmental Variables in the variable called PATH.

To do so on Windows:

1. Right mouse click on "My Computer" and select "properties"
2. Go to Advanced tab
3. In "Advanced" click on button "Environmental Variables"
4. In "System Variables" edit PATH entry adding `;` to the last entry
5. Save and restart terminal

EDIT: To run it like you want you should use `"` instead of `'`. So your command will look like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -version
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the path to the installed JAVA code to your enviroment `PATH` variable.  This will allow you to just type `java.exe` at the command line and have it find the executable without needing the full path.  Then you could type `java -help` to see the options available.